# Class \"League\\Flysystem\\UnableToWriteFile\" not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-9, laravel-storage

We have a laravel application that has a command to move some files from one s3 bucket (different account) to another s3 bucket.  This command runs once at day, and certainly every time it runs we get a log of the error stating:

```json
{
    "class": "Error",
    "message": "Class \"League\\Flysystem\\UnableToWriteFile\" not found",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "/var/www/our-application/vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/AwsS3V3Adapter.php:162",
    "trace": [
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/AwsS3V3Adapter.php:140",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:57",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php:331",
        "/var/www/our-application/app/Console/Commands/FileRetriever.php:79",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:653",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:312",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1022",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:314",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:168",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:102",
        "/var/www/our-application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:129",
        "/var/www/our-application/artisan:37"
    ]
}
```

I am planning to run `composer dump-autoload` at some point in the production servers.

Also, we are not able to reproduce this locally.

This is how the relevant libraries look like in our composer.json

[image]

Comment: If you are having that error "randomly" or "after some time", check your RAM usage. In the past, I did have issues with the RAM usage, and it went to 99% because of a lot of workers and I got a similar error like yours (a class not found when it was there). Check the memory usage every time

Comment: I think you hit the nail. Because of this comment I just realized something in this class/command that might trigger an memory leak and fill the php available memory really quick.

Comment: Try triggering the command or whatever is using that code, and also run `htop`, you should see live how it goes to 100% memory and boom, it crashes and gives you these weird not found errors and then goes down to an acceptable memory again

Comment: Yes, did that and makes total sense. Thanks for the help, I was hitting my head on understanding why these classes were not found on the server. I just came back to php after 15 years and is all different. If you convert your reply to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have this issue (but other classes not existing), after a long debugging session, I was able to reproduce this error, and, in my case, it was due to the virtual machine running out of memory (RAM) when some jobs where triggered.

So, do check if you have a memory issue by triggering the code and then (if you are using Linux) run `htop` so you can see live the memory consumption and disregard that being the issue or find out that is the issue.